# Use Windows 7 login for SonarQube login

Tags: sonarqube

I am on a Windows 7 standalone machine - no internet connection, no networking. I installed SonarQube 5.6.6 and scanner 3.0.3 to analyze some of my projects - it works great. There are 3 of us who have separate windows logins to this standalone machine and I would like to use that windows login as the login to SonarQube for each of our profiles. How do I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centralized authentication/authorization would typically be done with the [LDAP Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin). However if the machine is purely standalone (no networking as you said), then I presume user accounts are completely local, in which case the SonarQube accounts can only be managed locally by SonarQube too (i.e. SonarQube admin sets username/password).